# Displaying text in Vx675 with bigger text size

Tags: c++, c, verifone

how to increase font size in Vx675 . I m using set_font("somelagefont.vft") but it is not working. But when I did above thing in Vx520 it working fine. I have tried with many font files(.vft) in Vx675 but not able to display text with bigger size. 
I am using dispaly_at().